# Ignoring KeyErrors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I am implementing some functions to manipulate dataframes, and I have the reoccuring issue that the available columns may vary. As an example, take a list of payments that I want to group by year:

1. If the column 'currency' exists, I want to check if all datapoints are of the same currency before grouping
2. If the column 'project_id' exists, I want to also group by project_id, i.e. add it to the keys.

If the columns don't exist, I obviously just want to ignore them, as they are not relevant for the rest of the operations, but pandas throws KeyErrors instead. Of course I can micro-manage every case with try-catch, or intersect with the existing columns first, but is there a more generic approach to this? For example, `drop` has the keyword `errors='ignore'`, and I find this extremly convenient.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't provide your input I assume the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DF
data = {
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
    'amount': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'currency': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'EUR'],
    # 'project_id': [1, 2, 1, 2]  # Uncomment to test with 'project_id'
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

group_keys = ['year']

# Check for 'currency' column
if 'currency' in df.columns:
    if df['currency'].nunique() == 1:
        # All datapoints have the same currency, you can continue to group
        pass
    else:
        print("Data has multiple currencies!")

# Check for 'project_id' column
if 'project_id' in df.columns:
    group_keys.append('project_id')

grouped = df.groupby(group_keys).sum().reset_index()
print(grouped)
```

---

### EDIT :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
    'amount': [100, 200, 300, 400],
    'currency': ['USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'EUR'],
    'project_id': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'department': ['HR', 'Tech', 'Tech', 'Finance'],
    'region': ['West', 'East', 'East', 'North'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Dictionary of potential columns and their validation functions
# If no validation is required, use lambda df: True
potential_columns = {
    'year': lambda df: True,
    'currency': lambda df: df['currency'].nunique() <= 1,
    'project_id': lambda df: True,
    'department': lambda df: True,
    'region': lambda df: True,
    'another_column': lambda df: True,
}

# Using a list comprehension to filter columns
actual_keys = [col for col in potential_columns if col in df.columns and potential_columns[col](df)]

grouped = df.groupby(actual_keys).sum().reset_index()
print(grouped)
```

Comment: thanks, but this is exactly the kind of micro-managment I want to avoid. I don't want to test for every case, I just want to ignore any non-existing columns

Comment: Can you provide a dataset ?

Comment: Your dataset is a perfect example for this. Now how can you achieve this without all the if blocks? (like in `df.drop(['currency', 'foo'], errors='ignore')`)

Comment: @Yann given that you have a further condition on currency other than just its existence, how do your expect not to have to use an if block, at least in that case?

Comment: obviously I need an if to check for conditions. My point, as re-iterated multiple times now, is about not checking for non-existing columns

Comment: thanks, that looks way more generic already. I will leave the question open for the moment anyhow, as I am still hoping for a method to explicitly ignore them

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's Built-in Exceptions. Example:

```
try:
  print(x)
except NameError:
  print("Variable x is not defined")
except:
  print("Something else went wrong")
```

Print one message if the try block raises a NameError and another for other errors: